# how to convert this Query to Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

how to convert this query to linq :

```
Select top 1 COUNT(*)
From RateTable
Group by Rate
order by COUNT(*) desc
```

and this table SQL is :

```
Create Table RateTable ( RID int primary key , Rate int );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.RateTable
  .GroupBy(x => x.Rate) 
  .Select(g => g.Count())
  .OrderByDescending(g => g) 
  .First()
```

Comment: @Michael "Not working" is very seldom a helpful enough error description.

Comment: it might be .Select(g=>g.First()) instead of just .First()